Struggling to Fine-Tune LLaMA 3.2 Models: Why Does Base Model Outperform Instruct in My Use Case?
I’ve been trying to fine-tune the LLaMA 3.2-Instruct model on my custom dataset, which is in JSON-style chat format. The dataset is small (around 400 entries) and I can’t share it due to its confidential nature. After training the model and testing it, I noticed that the model didn’t adapt well to my dataset—the results seemed almost unchanged from the base model.
I tried modifying various parameters like the learning rate, but the issue persisted. Interestingly, when I switched to fine-tuning the LLaMA-3.2-1B-bnb-4bit model using the Alpaca prompt, I observed significantly better results for my specific use case. Many people have mentioned that Instruct models perform better with structured data, but that hasn’t been the case for me.
Even though the LLaMA-3.2-1B-bnb-4bit model worked better, the results are far from perfect, and I’m unsure why these differences occur despite using the same dataset. Here’s how I formatted my dataset and the parameters I used for fine-tuning for the Llama-3.2-1B-Instruct-bnb-4bit (instruct model):
Dataset Formatting Code
Description: The following code shows how I formatted my dataset into a JSON-style chat format suitable for fine-tuning. I used the unsloth.chat_templates library to standardize the ShareGPT format and map my dataset into the required format. The dataset was initially in a CSV file where conversations were stored as JSON strings.

tokenizer = get_chat_template(
    tokenizer,
    chat_template = "llama-3.1",
)

def formatting_prompts_func(examples):
    convos = examples["conversations"]
    texts = [tokenizer.apply_chat_template(convo, tokenize = False, add_generation_prompt = False) for convo in convos]
    return { "text" : texts, }

from datasets import load_dataset

import json
import pandas as pd
from datasets import Dataset

# Load the CSV
df = pd.read_csv('/content/conversation_style_dataset.csv')

# Parse the JSON strings in the "conversations" column
df['conversations'] = df['conversations'].apply(json.loads)

# Convert the pandas DataFrame to a Hugging Face Dataset
dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df)

# Standardize using ShareGPT formatting
from unsloth.chat_templates import standardize_sharegpt

# Apply the standardization and formatting functions
dataset = standardize_sharegpt(dataset)
dataset = dataset.map(formatting_prompts_func, batched=True)

Fine-Tuning Parameters
Description: Here are the fine-tuning parameters I used with the Hugging Face SFTTrainer class. I kept the training batch size small due to limited hardware resources and adjusted other parameters like the learning rate and optimizer. The training was run for one epoch to save time during experimentation.
from transformers import TrainingArguments, DataCollatorForSeq2Seq
from unsloth import is_bfloat16_supported

# Define the trainer for fine-tuning the model
trainer = SFTTrainer(
   model = model,
   tokenizer = tokenizer,
   train_dataset = dataset,
   dataset_text_field = "text",
   max_seq_length = max_seq_length,
   data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer = tokenizer),
   dataset_num_proc = 2,
   packing = False, # Can make training 5x faster for short sequences.
   args = TrainingArguments(
       per_device_train_batch_size = 2,
       gradient_accumulation_steps = 4,
       warmup_steps = 5,
       num_train_epochs = 1, # Set this for 1 full training run.
       learning_rate = 2e-4,
       fp16 = not is_bfloat16_supported(),
       bf16 = is_bfloat16_supported(),
       logging_steps = 1,
       optim = "adamw_8bit",
       weight_decay = 0.01,
       lr_scheduler_type = "linear",
       seed = 3407,
       output_dir = "outputs",
       report_to = "none", # Use this for WandB etc
   ),
)

My Questions:

Why does fine-tuning LLaMA-3.2-1B-bnb-4bit using the Alpaca prompt yield better results than LLaMA-3.2-Instruct-bnb-4bit, even when trained on the same data?

What is the best way to format my dataset to optimize results with instruct models?

Are there any resources or strategies for fine-tuning with such a small dataset?




Why does fine-tuning LLaMA-3.2-1B-bnb-4bit using the Alpaca prompt yield better results than LLaMA-3.2-Instruct-bnb-4bit, even when trained on the same data?

They are different models, so the were not trained on same data 1:1. Instruct model was finetuned additionaly with instruct data.
The case why base model performs better than instruct in some cases one is simple: the finetuning forced model to learn some different patterns better, so it "forgot" some generalization from previous training to be more inteligent in new learned cases. This is known behaviour.

What is the best way to format my dataset to optimize results with instruct models?

You need carefully materials of providers. You used Alpaca format - I don't think that Llama-3.2 got this format right. The format for Llama3.2 is different: see materials from Meta: https://www.llama.com/docs/model-cards-and-prompt-formats/llama3_2/:

The lightweight models share many characteristics with the Llama 3.1 text-only models. For information that is applicable across both sets of models, see the following sections on the Llama 3.1 page.

So format for Llama3.1 is applied:
<|begin_of_text|><|start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|>

Cutting Knowledge Date: December 2023
Today Date: 23 July 2024

You are a helpful assistant<|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|>

What is the capital of France?<|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|>

see: https://www.llama.com/docs/model-cards-and-prompt-formats/llama3_1/#-instruct-model-prompt-

Are there any resources or strategies for fine-tuning with such a small dataset?

Try out your best to check and engineer prompts; then if it does not work, curate the 1000 samples that are distributed as your final dataset and try to slightly finetune the model using last layers. See this excellent material about finetuning: also from META: https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.11206
